# jquery spellchecker how to access a text box on the page

Tags: jquery, spell-checking

I am using [jquery spellcheck](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/ckeditor.html) and implementing like below...

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('jqueryspellchecker', {    
    config: {
        lang: $('.cul').val,
    parser: 'html',
    disableNativeSpellChecker : false,
    webservice: {
      path: '/JQuerySpellCheckerHandler.ashx',
      driver: 'google'
    },
    suggestBox: {
      position: 'below',
      appendTo: 'body'
    },
    incorrectWords: {
        container: '#incorrect-word-list'
    }
  },

  init: function( editor ) {

    var t = this;
    var pluginName = 'jqueryspellchecker';

    this.config.suggestBox.position = this.positionSuggestBox();

    editor.addCommand(pluginName, {
      canUndo: false,
      readOnly: 1,
      exec: function() {
        t.toggle(editor);
      }
    });

    editor.ui.addButton('jQuerySpellChecker', {
      label: 'SpellCheck',
      command: pluginName
    });

    editor.on('saveSnapshot', function() {
      t.destroy();
    });
  },

  create: function() {
    this.createSpellchecker();
    this.editor.setReadOnly(true);
    this.spellchecker.check();
    this.editor.commands.jqueryspellchecker.toggleState();
  },

  destroy: function() {
    if (!this.spellchecker) 
      return;
    this.spellchecker.destroy();
    this.spellchecker = null;
    this.editor.setReadOnly(false);
    this.editor.commands.jqueryspellchecker.toggleState();
  },

  toggle: function(editor) {
    this.editor = editor;
    if (!this.spellchecker) {
      this.create();
    } else {
      this.destroy();
    }
  },

  createSpellchecker: function() {
      var t = this;

    t.config.getText = function () {
      //alert(t.editor.getData());
      //alert($(t.editor.container).attr("data-code"));      
      return $('<div >').append(t.editor.getData()).text();
    };

   // t.spellchecker = new $.SpellChecker($(t.editor.container), this.config);
    t.spellchecker = new $.SpellChecker('.cke_focus', this.config);
    t.spellchecker.on('check.success', function () {
      alert('There are no incorrectly spelt words.');
      t.destroy();
    });

    t.spellchecker.on('replace.word', function () {
      if (t.spellchecker.parser.incorrectWords.length === 0) {
        t.destroy();
      }
    });
  },

  positionSuggestBox: function() {

      var t = this;

    return function() {

      var ed = t.editor;
      var word = (this.wordElement.data('firstElement') || this.wordElement)[0];

      var p1 = $(ed.container.$).find('.cke_focus').offset();
      var p2 = $(ed.container.$).offset();
      var p3 = $(word).offset();

      var left = p3.left;
      var top = p3.top + word.offsetHeight;      

      this.container.css({ 
        top: top, 
        left: left  
      });
    };
  }
});
```

But how to I get a value of a text box on the page to set the language..`lang: $('.cul').val`

Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell which text box value your looking for? and why?

Comment: the textbox is the one with class .cul and to get the language value from that box

Comment: i want to set the language dynamically which is different per page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CKEDITOR plugin can access the current instance id using **editor.name** property.
And then using $('#'+editor.name) will give you the target textarea of current CKEDITOR.

Your writing the CKEDIOR plugin, so instead of having the seperate way to set the culture it should be part of target textarea. There you can set the HTML 5 based data attribute like **data-culture** which will give you the desired culture for target RichTextbox.

There might be some business scenarios where one page will have multiple RichTextBox controls each of which with different culture like online Google translator page.

Comment: By default you can set the lang:'en' or what ever. Then in 'init' you can get the correct culture value and set it there.